# Фильтрация и сортировка данных по секциям для UITableView

Tags: xcode, mvc, objective-c

Читаю анкету на Junior Objective-C developer и там встречаю такой вопрос:

> Приложение получает данные с сервера, которые нужно отфильтровать и отсортировать по секциям для UITableView. Как правильно организовать решение с точки зрения MVC?

Как бы Вы ответили на этот вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Завёл бы массив для секций, сами секции бы представлял в виде словаря с двумя ключами: заголовок секции (строка) и содержимое (массив).
2. Написал бы метод вида

   ```
    - (void)updateSectionsWithReceivedItems:(NSArray *)items_from_server;
   ```

   в котором бы разбирал полученные данные по супер-секретному алгоритму на секции (используя, например, `NSPredicate` для фильтрации объектов по каким-то параметрам), которые писал бы в массив, задуманный на шаге 1.
3. Ну и затем бы для методов `UITableViewDataSource`

   ```
    – tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  
    – numberOfSectionsInTableView:
    – tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:  
    – sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:
    – tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:
    – tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
    – tableView:titleForFooterInSection:
   ```

   использовал сформированный массив секций.

---

Вообще неоднозначный вопрос, как по мне − не хватает конкретики.

*P.S. скажите, что за анкета и где её можно найти?*

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу про анкету, тоже интересно

Comment: http://alterplay.com/job/serious-ios-developer-anketa.html 

это анкета одной из киевских фирм по разработке ПО

Comment: @AlexThumb, где же там `Junior`? Я вижу пока только `Serious` :).

Comment: они сами нашли мое крайне скромное резюме (стажер без опыта работы) и попросили заполнить анкету, так что никто не знает точно что они подразумевают под этой фразой)

Comment: По теме: в чем заключается применение MVC в приведенном ответе?

Comment: @AlexThumb этот ответ — то, как сделал бы я. Причём тут MVC — не знаю (сам вопрос к этому паттерну имеет лишь опосредованное отношение).

Comment: мне тоже так кажется, поэтому и запостил сюда с целью узнать действительно ли я что-то недопонял. Так или иначе благодарю, ответ принимается